# NodeMailer No Recipients Defined

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

When trying to send an email from a node.js server using nodemailer, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Send Error: No recipients defined
```

My code is as follows:

client side:

```
var mailData = {
        from: "myemail@gmail.com",
        to: "someoneelse@something.com",
        subject: "test",
        text: "test email"
    };

  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: mailData,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/sendEmail',
        success: function(mailData) {
            console.log('successfully posted to server.');
        }
    });
```

server side:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.post('/sendEmail', function(mailData) {

   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       service: 'gmail',
       auth: {
           user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
           pass: 'mypassword'
       },
   });

   transporter.sendMail(mailData, function(error, info) {
       if (error) {
           console.log(error);
           return;
       }
       console.log('Message sent');
       transporter.close();
   });

});
```

This is in line with the nodemailer docs, and the SMTP handshake always finishes successfully, so I know that this is not an issue with the transporter object.

Comment: Did you check how `mailData` var look like on server side just before running `sendMail` method? Is it the same as  on client side? Everything looks ok and this kind of error is thrown when `to` field is empty.

Comment: @kkochanski you're right. there is something wrong with the ajax on client side, as when I do console.log(mailData.to) on the server I get undefined, so the issue is actually with my ajax call and not nodemailer itself.

Comment: I answered, hope that helps!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This kind of error occurs when value assigned to key `to` in object given to `sendMail` method is empty. As we see it means that something wrong happens and you don't get the same data on the server-side, as you sent in client.

Also I recommend to check if you are accessing good variable on your server-side action. Probably POST params are accessible in different way - please check this in your framework documentation.

For example in HapiJS I retrieve POST params in that way:

```js
exports.someAction = function (request, reply) {
    var postParams = request.payload
}
```

Comment: yeah I realised this. Thanks a lot for your help.